# iPhone How to present photos from my documents directory?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary

I have been using UIImagePicker controller for taking photos and saving it to my documents directory. Now i want to be able to present them to user for picking. UIImagePicker has neat functionallity

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

When I set this property all images from library are presented. Is there some way I can use UIImagePicker to present my photos from documents directory?

Answer (score 2):

The only supported sources for the UIImagePicker are library, camera or saved photo album.  See UIImagePickerControllerSourceType @ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

```
enum {
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
   UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
};
typedef NSUInteger UIImagePickerControllerSourceType;
```